# Custom Loop and Standard Blog Loop Issue

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I am working on a theme with a front page that will have two loop sections. The first will loop three posts from a Custom Post Type (ill-portfolio), the second will loop three blog posts. In both instances I want the posts to be generated in a `<ul>`. I am also using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin on the page.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

```
<section id="recent-work-wrapper" class="row">

    <aside id="recent-work" class="col-3 float">
        <h3><?php the_field('home_work_title'); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_field('home_work_paragraph'); ?></p>
    </aside>

    <!--CUSTOM POST TYPE LOOP-->
    <ul class="home-recent-posts">
        <?php 
            query_posts('post_type=ill-portfolio&posts_per_page=3');
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
        ?>

        <li class="home-single-post col-3 float">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">View Project</a>
        </li>

        <?php endwhile; endif;?>
    </ul>

</section>

<!--Recent Posts Section-->
<section id="recent-posts-wrapper" class="row">

    <aside id="recent-posts" class="col-3">
        <h3><?php the_field('home_posts_title'); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_field('home_posts_paragraph'); ?></p>
    </aside>

    <!--BLOG POST LOOP-->   
    <ul class="home-recent-posts">
        <?php 
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
        ?>

        <li class="home-single-post col-3 float">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">View Project</a>
        </li>

        <?php endwhile; endif;?>
    </ul>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using query_post(), you can reset the query at the end by using

```
<?php 
        query_posts('post_type=ill-portfolio&posts_per_page=3');
.
.
.
<?php endwhile; endif;?>

<?php
// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```